# How do I optimize the code so that I don't have to write a new number every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, lightgallery

I have js code like this:

```
 lightGallery($("#web1")[0], {
    selector: 'this',
    mobileSettings: {
        controls: false,
        showCloseIcon: true,
        download: false,
    }
});
lightGallery($("#web2")[0], {
    selector: 'this',
    mobileSettings: {
        controls: false,
        showCloseIcon: true,
        download: true,
    }
});
lightGallery($("#web3")[0], {
    selector: 'this',
    mobileSettings: {
        controls: false,
        showCloseIcon: true,
        download: true,
    }
});
```

How do I optimize the code so that I don't have to write a new number every time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to use `.each()` to iterate each item. Then it's am matter of the correct selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$("[id^='web']").each(function(i, el){
  lightGallery($(el)[0], {
    selector: 'this',
    mobileSettings: {
      controls: false,
      showCloseIcon: true,
      download: false,
    }
  });
});
```

This will go over each one that has an ID that starts `web` and apply the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop:

```js
let lowerLimit = 1;
let upperLimit = 3;

for (let i = lowerLimit; i <= uppperLimit; i++) {
    lightGallery($("#web" + i)[0], {
        selector: 'this',
        mobileSettings: {
            controls: false,
            showCloseIcon: true,
            download: false,
        }
    });
}
```